# Is there any way to get a list of corrupted document files either in Windows 10 or other software?

Tags: windows, file-search

I mean docs, images, files with gibberish characters in them, etc. Not system files.

I had an SSD which had some documents on. Without going into too much confusing detail, I ended up merging some partitions on the drive. When I rebooted my documetns were gon. So I ran an undeleter and recovered what I could onto a different drive. Many of the files I recovered "cannot be read" by the various apps that should be able to open them; psd, doc, docx, all the usual ones.

I'm left with over 300k files (a mixture of office docs, images and software files). Some of these can be opened and some cannot. I'm not loving the idea of going through each one individually to see if it will open, so is there a software choice?

I used a program called Bad Peggy, which identified a lot of image files that were corrupted, but is there a similar app for other types of files?

Cheers

Comment: I guess you need to make a more or less complete list of file types which you subsummized under "all the usual ones", find out how many of them you have, and look for a solution for each of them individually. Hopefully you learnt from the incident that it is a good idea to make regular backups ;-)

Comment: Cheers, Doc. As it happens, I do have boackups, I just don't like "throwing anything out", LOL.

Answer (score 1):

MS office and Open/Libre Office documents are zip files, so you can use
the command-line version of unzip to test their integrity. (unless they are from a really old ms-office version)

For the pictures something like image magick or fly can possibly probably do the same thing.

Comment: That's in idea! I'll give it a try, thanks.